# Joining csv files in a directory having more than 10 rows in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a lot of csv files with same type of columns in a directory and I want to join them to form a single csv file. Now the following code imports all of them into one data frame:

```
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE, pattern="*.csv")

abc = do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = ','))
```

Now, in this directory, the csv files having less than 10 rows have one column less than the others. So, when I run the code for all files in the directory, I get the following error message: `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match`

So, I want to do either of the two things:

1. Join all the files irrespective of some having a column less than the others (which I believe is a little too much to ask!)
   or,
2. More rationally, involve some condition involving `nrow>=10` while joining and join those having more than 10 rows and identical no. of columns.

But, I can't successfully add the condition involving `nrow` for all files. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE, pattern="*.csv")
dfs <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
dfs1 <- do.call(rbind, datasets[sapply(datasets, nrow) != 10]
dfs2 <- do.call(rbind, datasets[sapply(datasets, nrow) == 10]
```

This assumes all that have less than 10 columns have the same number of columns (say 9). Otherwise, you can inspect `sapply(datasets, nrow)` to see how many variations you have and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @asb, but in this case the files having less than 10 rows are at least 20 in number and they have different no. of rows.

Comment: @souravsarkar59: In that case probably your attempt is misguided. You can choose to pad these `data.frame`s with `NA` columns if you think that makes sense. After that you can rbind them all.

Answer (score 2):

First read in the files as you were doing but don't `rbind()` yet.

```
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE, pattern="*.csv")
files <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
```

You can combine the data as long as they all have the same columns, so here's a way of adding in any missing columns before you do the combining:

```
n <- unique(unlist(sapply(files, names)))
cleaned <- lapply(files, function (l) {
  l[, n[!n %in% names(l)]] <- NA
  return (l)
})
do.call(rbind, cleaned)
```

It finds every unique column across all files (`n`) and then makes sure every data frame has those columns before doing the `rbind()` (columns are filled with `NA` if missing).

---

For your part 2), I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for. I'm taking it that any file with 10 or more rows have the exact same columns, and any files with less than 10 rows also have the same columns. To `rbind()` only those with more than ten rows, you can filter out the ones that don't meet that criteria:

```
filterRows <- function (x) nrow(x) >= 10
do.call(rbind, Filter(filterRows, files))
```

Or if you want both those with more and less than ten rows as separate sets you can do:

```
filters <- c(filterRows, Negate(filterRows))
filtered <- lapply(filters, Filter, files)
result <- lapply(filtered, function(l) do.call(rbind, l))
```

`result` there will contain all >= 10 row data in the first element, all other files in the second element.